# How can I remove a folder from the itunes library

Tags: windows, itunes

I added a folder (a network share) to the iTunes media library (File -> Add Folder to library).
I didn't find a way I can undo this operation.
What am I missing? how can I remove this folder from the iTunes library?

I am using iTunes 10.2 in Windows 7 32bit.
Edit: I configured iTunes not to copy media files locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your iTunes preferences.

1.If iTunes is running default, iTunes actually copied all that media to your local drive, and you would have to delete it manually via sorting by "Date Added" to remove it.

2.If you have iTunes set to reference the files, when you disconnect the drive iTunes has some pretty annoying behavior where it will try to maintain the link but it will become a ghost music icon, the best way to get rid of these is sort by "Date Added" in your library and remove them manually.

These behaviors can be checked under iTunes preferences, I copied this pic from the Apple support site under [HT1751](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1751):[image: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1751]

Comment: I actually configured it not to copy media to its local library

Comment: Then it sounds like it is a sort by date added and shift click to delete. iTunes is assumes you will want huge share on your local hard drive and no music would ever want to move around :>